# Break points are not setting up for some lines in intellij

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

While setting break points in intellij for debugging a java project . I couldn't set line break points at some places.

Methods I followed for debugging .

- Go to `Run-> Debug` in IntelliJ. It will give a dialog box and click on
  `Edit Configurations`.
- Then give a name such ( I have given Remote-debugger) and press OK.
  I set Host: localhost and Port:5005 have been set.
- Go Run->Debug ‘' ( `Run-> Debug Remote-debugger` in my
  case)
- Started the server

[image]

As you can see above, for some lines the break points get added and for some line it is not . **WHY** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It most likely is because the remote code that you are debugging is different than the source code and the lines that are you are putting a break point on are not code lines. You have to make sure your source code matches the binary that's on your remote host by checking out exactly the same revision from your source control.

Comment: That is right! Some of source code lines may be inlined by compiler.

Comment: Got it :) . It is due to version mismatching. After matching the versions of remote server and source code, it works. Thanks !